# OpenLayers 4 - Draw Rectangle

Tags: openlayers

I just want to draw rectangle in for style.

if I do this

```
 image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
            fill: fill,
            //stroke: stroke,
            // offsetY: -25,
            points: 4,
            radius1: 30,
            //radius2:20,
            angle: Math.PI / 4
        })
```

it gives me this 
[image]

else if i do this

```
 image: new ol.style.RegularShape({
            fill: fill,
            //stroke: stroke,
            // offsetY: -25,
            points: 4,
            radius1: 30,
            radius2:10,
            angle: Math.PI / 4
        })
```

it gives me this 
[image]

How can I draw rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot draw a rectangle with `ol.style.RegularShape`, because a rectangle is not a regular shape. Instead, you can use an `ol.style.Icon` with a custom canvas:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
canvas.width = 60;
canvas.height = 20;
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);;

var imageStyle = new ol.style.Icon({
  img: canvas,
  imgSize: [60, 20]
});
```